# Switching Git workflow from merge to rebase: how to clean up a merge commit history?

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-rewrite-history

I'm trying to have a good Git workflow for contributing to an open source project (Endless Sky), but learning as I started out I've not ended up with a clean history. My workflow now is:

1. `upstream/master` is [here](https://github.com/endless-sky/endless-sky).
2. My fork is [here](https://github.com/Elyssaen/endless-sky). I started using GitHub Desktop, but am beginning to switch to the command line.
3. My fork's master is supposed to mirror the `upstream/master`. Each feature I develop has a branch to itself, created from my master, and I use my own (local) `alpha` and (pushed) `beta` branches for combining my features to test/play.

My problem is on my forked master: `This branch is 15 commits ahead of endless-sky:master.` No files changed; it's merge commit messages. This seemed ugly to me, so I did some reading, particularly the article [Stop using 'git pull': A better workflow](https://adamcod.es/2014/12/10/git-pull-correct-workflow.html), and I've switched to rebasing/fast-forwarding.

But what's the best way to clean up an existing merge commit history in this situation? It touches a few of my feature branches too (see: `feature/JammingHaywire`), and I don't want to be submitting a PR where the meaningful commits are drowned by meaningless merge commits.

I've read various other questions and am not quite clear whether I'm best:

1. deleting/remaking `master` — is that safe, particularly with GitHub?
2. trying to do a `git rebase -i [which commit?]` back to some point — doesn't seem to work. Tried it back to `0facf00`, some commit *long* before I forked, and my merge commit hashes (e.g. `3be4d97` seen on GitHub) don't show up in the text file to drop. The end result is unchanged.
3. doing something else I haven't thought of yet? Is what I'm trying to do 'good practice' in the first place?

Comment: I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your post to add a link to the article you mentioned. If that isn't the right one, feel free to update or remove it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I couldn't add a third link at the time (starting user limit), so that's a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option, deleting and recreating `master`, is probably the easiest. Here's how you can clean things up:

1. If you haven't already, switch to `master`:

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. Create a backup branch, just in case:

   ```
   git branch backup
   ```
3. Reset `master` to match that of `upstream`. This is effectively the same as deleting and recreating the branch, your option 1, but only requires one command:

   ```
   git reset --hard upstream/master
   ```
4. Force-push:

   ```
   git push --force-with-lease origin master
   ```

   <sub>Obligatory **warning**: Since a rebase rewrites history, this can be dangerous / disruptive for anyone else working on this branch. Be sure you clearly communicate what you have done with anyone you are collaborating with. Since this is a personal fork, I assume this won't be an issue for you.</sub>

Your `master` branch is now up to date with `upstream/master`, so on GitHub you should see:

```
This branch is even with endless-sky:master.
```

If you find later that you are missing anything, you can look through the history of `backup` to find it.

To fix any feature branches that were similarly mangled, do:

```
git checkout myfeature
git rebase -i master
```

Your editor will open and you will see a list of commits. Delete any lines containing the extra merges, then save and exit. Again push with `--force-with-lease`.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is on my forked master: "This branch is 15 commits ahead of endless-sky:master." No files changed; it's merge commit messages.

Let's start there:

reset your fork master to endless-sky/master

Assuming you have cloned your fork:

```
cd /path/to/fork/clone
git checkout master
git remote add-url endless-sky /url/of/endless-sky
git fetch endless-sky
git reset --hard endless-sky/master
git push --force
```

Now, checkout any of your feature branch (that you intent to make a PR from), and rebase it on your master branch (which also represents `endless-sky/master` now)

```
git checkout my_feature_branch
git rebase master
git push --force
```